# Can I use SSL certificates using truststore and keystore in BIRT Report Designer to connect to database?

Tags: java, ssl, birt

Can I use SSL certificates using truststore and keystore in BIRT  Report Designer to connect to database?

Answer (score 0):

You must copy the SSL cert from the server to a file, import the certificate in the java keystore, and modify the WSDL URL or Location field in Eclipse.
Here is a step by step guide to configure [Setting up the DataSource](https://kb.groundworkopensource.com/display/DOC71/Creating+BIRT+Reports#CreatingBIRTReports-2.0SettinguptheDataSource)

Comment: Can i use the above way to connect to db2 also ?

Comment: yes @Soumya, you can do that [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTPTP_1.3.0/com.ibm.netcool_ops.doc_1.3.0/itnm/ip/wip/install/task/nmip_con_configuringdb2datasourcesforbirt.html)

Comment: i could not able to add truststore and keystore to connect db2 datasource in BIRT . Am i missing anything ?. Let me know

Comment: Basically i am using mysql and section 2.1 is written about webservice ssl connection using wsdl . Correct if i am wrong . Again thank you for helping me .